# Pro:Idiom not running on samsung Tizen 3.0

Tags: encryption, avplayer, tizen, tizen-web-app, iptv

I am trying to run the Pro:Idiom video using the udp URL, but it's not getting decrypted. My Samsung Tv is using Tizen OS version 3.0 and here is the code below:

```
try{
  var drmParam = new Object();
  drmParam.ForensicData = "abcvdfdsfsadfasdfafda";
  webapis.avplay.setDrm("PROIDIOM", "Initialize", JSON.stringify(drmParam));
  webapis.avplay.open("udp://238.255.4.3:5000");
  webapis.avplay.setDisplayRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
  webapis.avplay.prepare();
  webapis.avplay.play();
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Also, I am not sure about the forensic data, how to get it ?

Comment: You can find setDrm() code example from https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/api-references/samsung-product-api-references/avplay-api.html

Comment: I had tried this already but it's not working for the Pro:Idiom, also there is no such information for Pro:Idiom